# Topology: Cuts on a surface

Tags: general-topology

I'm self-studying [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8n5eL.png).
Fig 4.48 of the book is as follows;
[image]
Note that

- $E_i$ are the extended complex plane $\mathbb{C} \cup \{ \infty \}$,
- We are considering $p(z) = (z - a) (z - b) (z - c)$,
- $s_a$, $s_b$, and $s_c$ are branch points

And the book doesn't have much explanation on this transformation other than saying

> If we open out the cuts on $E_1$ and $E_2$, then (as illustrated in Fig.4.48) we see that $E_1$ and $E_2$ are homeomorphic to the two halves of a torus.

I was trying to understand that by inflating, say, $E_1$ in the first row of the figure, we can somehow get the figures on the 2nd row... But so far no idea how we can transition from the first row to the second row... Could anyone help?

### Edit

I could see that as $E_i$ are the sphere, we can have the sphere w/h 2 handles before moving to the second row of Fig.4.48;
[image]

But still not sure how to go from here to the 2nd row.

### Reference

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8n5eL.png) Jones, Gareth A., and David Singerman. Complex functions: an algebraic and geometric viewpoint. Cambridge university press, 1987.

Comment: Are we supposed to guess what are $E_1$ and $E_2$?

Comment: sorry, $E_i$ are the extended complex plane $\mathbb{C} \cup \{ \infty \}$.

Comment: Thank you, but don't answer that in a comment, people reading your question shouldn't have to read the comments to understand it.

Comment: yeah, I just edited my question! Thanks for your note!

Comment: So $E_1$ is a sphere. After you make to cuts and open those cuts you get a sphere with two holes. Now pull  out the borders of those holes to get what you have in figure 2.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i could follow till the sphere w/h two handles (or holes as you say). Could you elaborate the opration of pulling out the `borders`? Like where have the holes of E1 sphere gone in Figure 2...?

Comment: I saw more edits after posting my answer and thought maybe I was missing some detail and there was more to this.  Just imagine cutting two small holes in a thick rubber balloon and having it not deflate, then imagine you can stretch it out like clay at the holes.  Once you've cut these holes each of the figures is an open cylinder. The way the M's and L's are labeled in the last figure makes it look like there is something odd here but I am sure it's just how they were sketched in and the identification is just that border meets border to form a torus.

Comment: @jjagmath I think I've got it! I was thinking that $E_i$ in the 1st figure as surface,,, that's where I went wrong... thus, there was a sphere w/h two handles in my head for each $E_i$,,, but cuts are just cuts on the sphere... Thanks!

Comment: @AlgTop1854 Thank you for your detailed answer! As I wrote above, my imagination was wrong from the beginning! I was imagining the cut (say M1 and M2) are going through the sphere to make a handle! Anyway, thank you for your clarification!

Comment: Well before the cuts they are surfaces (spheres) and after they are surfaces with boundary (open cylinders).  If the last step reminds you of a surgeon grafting an artery, this process is an example of - you guessed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we assume that $E_1$ and $E_2$ are each the 2-sphere (the surface of a ball) then this sequence is depicting the following:

(1) cut 2 non-intersecting holes in each ball

(2) At each hole stretch a little to produce the small “pipes” protruding

(3) The resulting shapes now are the same (homeomorphic) to the cardboard tube from a roll of toilet paper. This could have been shown as an intermediate step.

(4) Bend these tubes towards each other (shown) then glue them together (not shown) and get a Torus (surface of a bagel)

This is similar to the operation called connected sum which is sewing together after cutting one hole.

Comment: As we also discussed in the thread above, This makes sense! Thank you!